# Service to remove all white space from a string?

Tags: terminal, applescript

I'm ultimately looking to create a service that will allow me to count all selected non-whitespace characters.  To get there though, I'm looking for a way to remove all whitespace characters from a string in a service that I can then use for other such purposes.  For example, I mainly want to use it to get quick DNA coordinates while looking at output in Terminal.app, but I can think of other uses, like counting code characters.

I have found applescripts to remove spaces, but nothing I've found appears to account for tabs, newline characters, carriage returns, or any other strange or weird character that doesn't display.

Note: I don't want to create a file or use or change the clipboard.

Side-question: Is there a way to display the result (briefly) in a bezel, like the way you can display phone numbers from the Contacts app?

Comment: “not create a file”—not even a temporary one?  I frequently put intermediate results in /tmp/tmp knowing that I will either soon overwrite it or the next boot will remove it.

Comment: I could write my own solution if I was willing to do it with temporary files. I was wondering how to do it without any files (feels cleaner that way).

Comment: After more than thirty years cleaning up messes in code, I can understand wanting to “feel cleaner.”  But sometimes I have to force myself to resist details that don’t really matter.  For code that needs to last, readable is more important than elegant.

Comment: Is there a way to pipe the selection as stdin to a command and replace the selection with stdout?  The regex in perl would be 's:\S::'

Comment: Yeah, it’s a very simple perlre, but you don’t have it quite right. It would be s:\s::gs. You need the s at the end for \s to match new lines, but I don’t think that covers carriage returns. For that, you’d need s:[\r\s]:gs. That’s how I would have done it if I were to use a file. I wouldn’t trust echoing, especially if it’s multi-line. That’s the first thing that comes to mind. But really, the AppleScript solution is what I was looking for. It doesn’t handle weird characters, but it’s good enough.

Comment: I didn't know about the 's' modifier, but I am embarrassed that I put 'S' instead of 's' !

Comment: It's all good.  I knew what you meant.

Comment: In one of your comments you said "It doesn’t handle weird characters, but it’s good enough."... The _weird characters_ could be added to the list of delimiters which would then remove them. Also if I had seen a representative sample, I might have coded it differently. What I posted was an example and certainly can be modified to account of other conditions.

Comment: Sure. I just don't know what to expect. What I mean by "weird" whitespace characters is anything other than a space, tab, newline, or carriage return that doesn't display any visible character.  I've encountered weird stuff in the past in files people have sent me, but I never really thought hard about it. I just filtered stringently for what I wanted as opposed to what I couldn't identify.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In **Automator**, create a new *Service* with the following settings:

- Service receives selected [text] in [Terminal]

Add a **Run AppleScript** *actions*, replacing the default *code* with the *code* below:

*Example* **AppleScript** code:

```
on run {input, parameters}

    set selText to item 1 of input as text
    set AppleScript's text item delimiters to {space, tab, linefeed, return}
    set selText to text items of selText
    set AppleScript's text item delimiters to {}
    set selText to selText as string

    display dialog ¬
        "The selection contains " & (count characters of selText) ¬
        & " characters." & linefeed & linefeed & selText ¬
        buttons {"OK"} default button 1

end run
```

Save the **Automator** *Service* as, e.g.: **Count Selected Characters**

Now in **Terminal**, select the wanted *selection*, e.g:

[image: Selected Text]

Right-click and select **Count Selected Characters** from the **Services** *context menu*.

Example *output* of the *selection* show above:

[image: Display Dialog]

---

**Note:** The *example* **AppleScript** *code* is just that and does not employ any *error handling* and is meant only to show one of many ways accomplish a task. The onus is always upon the User to add/use appropriate *error handling* as needed/wanted.

Comment: Awesome. Thanks so much. I knew someone would know how to do this!

Answer (score 0):

You could try WordService. [DEVONtechnologies](http://www.devontechnologies.com/download/products.html).

It is freeware, and does what you want (choose *Services -> WordService: Statistics*) plus a lot more.

Here's the result with a selection on your question:
[image]

From top to bottom:
Characters
Spaces
Total
Words
Lines

Comment: This is a nice utility, I've used it for many years, however this question is about Terminal and AppleScript, not some third-party utility and this does not really answer the question within the scope as asked.

Comment: **"I'm looking to create a service that will allow me to count all selected non-whitespace characters"**, Wordservice does this & it works with terminal output.

Comment: Yes, but I can’t use the output to count nucleotides. I want a string back, though I admit I didn’t ask this explicitly.

Comment: I edited the question to clear up the confusion of what I was looking for.  You're right, it was not very clear.